# quarkus: how to provide token over rest client

Tags: rest, security, testing, token, quarkus

In a unit test I call an @Authenticated endpoint via a REST client (over a @RegisterRestClient annotated interface). How do I provide a token in the REST call?

Answer (score 4):

The interface :

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient;

@RegisterRestClient
public interface MyAuthenticatedService {

    @GET
    public void myAuthenticatedCall(@HeaderParam("Authorization") String token);

}
```

And the call itself :

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RestClient;

public class FoobarService {

    @Inject
    @RestClient
    MyAuthenticatedService myService;

    public void foobar(String token) {
        myService.myAuthenticatedCall("Bearer " + token); // beware of the space
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to automatically pass the token to your rest client, do the following:

- Add `@RegisterClientHeaders` annotation to your interface
- Add `org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.propagateHeaders=Authorization` to your application.properties (where `Authorization` is the Request Header key name)